# Are men and women equal or not? Galatians 3:26-29 vs 1 Timothy 2:11-15

Tags: contradiction, galatians, 1-timothy, gender

On the one hand, they appear to be equal:

> 26 For you are all **sons and daughters** of God through faith in Christ Jesus. 27 For all of you who were baptized into Christ have clothed yourselves with Christ. 28 There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free, **there is neither male nor female**; for you are all one in Christ Jesus. 29 And if you belong to Christ, then you are Abraham’s descendants, heirs according to promise. [Galatians 3:26-29 NASB]

But on the other hand, some discrimination there appears to exist:

> 11 A woman must quietly receive instruction with entire submissiveness. 12 **But I do not allow a woman to teach or to exercise authority over a man**, but to remain quiet. 13 **For it was Adam who was first created, and then Eve**. 14 And it was not Adam who was deceived, **but the woman was deceived** and became a wrongdoer. 15 But women will be preserved through childbirth—if they continue in faith, love, and sanctity, with moderation. [1 Timothy 2:11-15 NASB]

How can we reconcile these two (seemingly contradictory) passages?

Comment: Equal in what? Humanity? Status before God? Role? Delegated authority?

Comment: @curiousdannii - Fair point. Equal in every respect they can be equal as long as it is biologically possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logical equivalence**

Computer science offers some helpful definitions:

- “Equal” does not mean “same”
- “Equal” means “same value”

Therefore, I can accurately state that (5+3) = (6+2). The expressions on each side of the equivalence are not the same, but they are equal.

--

**Domineer**

The verb sometimes translated “to exercise authority over” is αὐθεντέω; it is found nowhere else in the New Testament, and could more appropriately be translated “to domineer” (see [here](https://biblehub.com/greek/831.htm)).

--

**Quietness**

The word here is ἡσυχία which connotes being tranquil & calm. It does not mean speechless—that would be σιγή (see [here](https://biblehub.com/greek/2271.htm)).  It is noteworthy that the related word ἡσύχιος (again, tranquil) is applied to men & women in verse 2.

--

**The Historical Context—Ephesus & the cult of Diana**

Timothy was leading the church in Ephesus (1 Timothy 1:3), a major city in its region, where Paul himself had lived for more than 2 years (see Acts 19). This means Paul had quite a bit of personal knowledge regarding the people in Ephesus and the problems they faced.

Ephesus was home to the temple of Diana and was a hotspot for the worship of Diana (see Acts 19:23-28). In some expressions of the lore, believers in Diana saw her as the goddess of pregnancy, and would seek her protection during childbirth (see [here](https://www.gods-and-goddesses.com/roman/diana/)).

The cult of Diana interpretation is interesting because Paul was just cautioning against hairstyles they were known for in verse 9 (see Stott's work [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0830819924) p. 84). It seems likely that this advice, and quite possibly the advice in the surrounding verses, is specifically targeted to help the church avoid domineering and immoral practices common to Ephesus and the cult of Diana.

In this case, Paul is telling Timothy, when a woman comes to you with concern about childbirth and is considering Diana worship, here is the counsel to give her: she will be saved by the true and living God, and His blessings will be poured out if she and her husband are faithful.

Note that “saved” here could mean physical protection or it could have in mind an eternal blessing, or both. In other words, whether the blessings come in this life or in eternity, they will come from the true and living God, not from Diana.

(Additional context re the cult of Diana can be found in the aforementioned work by Stott, with summaries in my thoughts on a related question [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/56112/what-is-the-context-1-timothy-2/56132#56132), and an article by Gregory Brown [here](https://bible.org/seriespage/6-conduct-women-worship-1-timothy-29-15))

--

**Presentism**

The idea that there is no difference between men and women is not to be found in any ancient text that I am aware of, including the Bible. That they have the *same value* is found in the Bible, as noted in the OP.

The roles and identities of men & women are a major social topic today; but to expect the views of today to be found more-or-less identically-reflected in texts written millennia ago is known as the fallacy of presentism—to superimpose on the past the worldview of today.

If you’re looking for a rubber-stamp for a particular modern philosophy, a letter written circa AD 63 probably won’t give it to you. If you’re looking for profound theology, there the text may be of  great value.

--

**An educated guess on Paul's overall point - the tie in to Adam & Eve**

[This](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27889/1-timothy-215-she-and-they-one-woman-or-all-women?noredirect=1&lq=1) related question points out the unusual shifts between singular and plural in this chapter.

Verses 13 & 14 are about Adam and Eve. If they are the antecedents for verse 15, “she” is a reference to Eve and “they” means Adam & Eve. Then Paul might be saying something like this:

Redemption from the Fall will come because Eve will safely carry into the world descendants, from whom will come her Savior. Christ is of the seed of Eve, and so her Salvation is indeed a result of her motherhood (see Genesis 3:15 as well as Dottard’s post [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48076/enmity-between-the-serpent-and-the-woman)). Her role as a mother is a critical part of God’s plan to offer salvation to her and to the entire human family.

What about the “they”? Adam isn’t off the hook here. Eve does the child-bearing, but both mother and father have a sacred duty—together—to bring up their family in “faith and love and holiness, with self-control.” The righteous branch of their posterity, from which Christ will come, is borne by Eve, but is to be raised & taught by *both Adam and Eve*.

--

**Conclusion**

Paul recognizes the vital roles played by men & women of faith. There is no "greater" or "lesser" because we "are all one in Christ Jesus," and what we have in common is greater than what we have in difference--across any set of variables--because "we are the children of God." (Romans 8:16)

For a deeper dive on how I believe God Himself feels on this issue, see my thoughts in the latter half of the video found [here](https://youtu.be/MZ82YqJhe2g).

Comment: So, do you think that a woman can teach in the Church? I certainly agree that **none** (neither men nor women) should domineer(αὐθεντέω), and **all** (both men and woman) should be calm(ἡσύχιος). But what about the teaching situation? There are many people who teach in a non-domineering, calm manner. Could a woman do so in the Church? What is your view on that? Also, +1.

Comment: Thanks! *do you think a woman can teach in the church*? Yes! My thoughts in [this video](https://youtu.be/MZ82YqJhe2g). I also believe that neither men nor women should not take it upon themselves to act in God's name without God's permission to do so (see Hebrews 5:4, Exodus 20:7)

Comment: "*Yes!*" I do too! :) But what is your view on 1 Corinthians 14:34-35? Also, do you think a woman can pray/prophesy in the Church(with or without a head-covering, either way)?

Comment: @Rajesh - I review 1 Cor 14 specifically in the video =). What constitutes respectful vs extreme dress & grooming varies significantly from culture to culture. In my own faith I believe modern prophets have given [specific guidance](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/for-the-strength-of-youth/dress-and-appearance?lang=eng) for our time. As for prayer, I believe the key is to be reverent & respectful, the specific attire that conveys respect from culture to culture need not be the same.

Comment: "*I review 1 Cor 14 specifically in the video*" Good to know, thanks. "*In my own faith I believe modern prophets have given specific guidance for our time.*" Also good to know. "*As for prayer, I believe the key is to be reverent & respectful, the specific attire that conveys respect from culture to culture need not be the same.*" To be clear, I was asking "*can* a woman pray in Church", not "*should* women of all times/cultures pray in Church", as in, do you think there is a Biblical basis for allowing women to pray in the congregation/assembly? :)

Comment: @Rajesh my bad I misread your question. I do not believe there is any Biblical basis for prohibiting women from praying in church.

Comment: Hi HTTR. I have a question. Do you think Paul was clarifying "teach" with "domineer over a man"? Do you think 1 Tim. 2:12 could be read like this: I do not permit a woman to teach, or(in other words) to domineer over a man. Now I know what you're thinking; how can a woman domineer over a man by teaching? Simple; by teaching a doctrine that a woman can use to justify having power over a man, such as that man originated from woman, and that man was the first transgressor who was deceived. There is evidence that new converts could have blended in beliefs from their pagan past(i.e. syncretism).

Comment: New woman converts to Christianity might have brought in certain pagan beliefs that could've been used against men in the congregation if they were to teach them. And it seems like they did teach them(judging by the apostle Paul's words) and used what they were teaching against the men in the congregation(i.e. "domineering"[αὐθεντέω] over them). So, not only were they teaching false doctrines, but they were teaching false doctrines that they were using to subjugate men. This explains the apostle's strong exhortation. Do you think this could be the meaning of verses 12-14?...

Comment: "*I do not permit a woman to teach(certain doctrines, e.g. that woman came before man or that man was the original transgressor), that is, to domineer over a man, rather she is not to cause a disturbance. For(I giving justification for why a woman must not teach such doctrines, namely because they are false) Adam was first formed, then Eve, and Adam was not deceived, but the woman, being thoroughly deceived, fell into transgression.*" V.13-14 are meant to set the record straight, and correct certain women's erroneous teachings(that were being used to diminish men). So what do you think?

Comment: @Rajesh that is an interesting line of thought. Paul's switch from talking about "women" to discussion of "a woman" *might* indicate he has a specific, disruptive woman in Ephesus in mind...not sure though. I believe Paul wouldn't want a woman or a man to teach in a domineering way, or to spread false doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

The context of 1 Timothy 2:11-15 is dealing with function and behavior in the assembly. The context in Galatians 3:28 is unity in the body, not individual function in the Church. Whether one is male or female has absolutely no bearing on one’s relationship to God. Whether one is male or female, one is still “sons of God…, baptized into Christ…, clothed with Christ…, one in Christ…, belong to Christ…," both are "Abraham’s descendants, and heirs according to promise.” In the application of these blessings, there is no difference between male and female, slave or free.

In 1 Timothy 2 and 1 Corinthians 14, Paul is very clear that the distinction between male and female does indeed exist in the Church and that it does matter when it comes to divinely assigned functions. To counter any opposition to the prohibition Paul adds that women in the assembly are to keep silent and not speak, not even to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Men and women are equal in the eyes of God. Equality, however, does not imply identity in functions. Men and women serve different functional purposes in practice.

From the point of view of admission into the kingdom of God, male and female are equal:

> Galatians 3:28 There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free, there is neither male nor female; for you are all one in Christ Jesus.

We are all one in Christ. Unity does not mean sameness.

On earth, at a particular time, Paul wrote in
1 Timothy 2:12

> But I do not allow a woman to teach or to exercise authority over a man, but to remain quiet.

This needs to be balanced by Luke 10:39

> She had a sister called Mary, who sat at the **Lord's feet** listening to what he said.

A woman can be as close to the Lord as any man during a sermon. Men and women are equal in this practical sense on earth.

> 1 Timothy 2:13 For it was Adam who was first created, and then Eve. 14 And it was not Adam who was deceived, but the woman was deceived and became a wrongdoer.

These are facts and should be read factually and objectively. It does not logically imply that men and women are not equal.

Are men and women equal or not?

In the eyes of God, emphatically yes, despite that some men may think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

No - man and women are **not** equal. They are one. Equality amongst people is not a biblical concept. Judging, seeking or ‘assigning’  ‘equality’ between ‘humans’ is a man centred doctrine. Where as the Bible sees ‘man’ as ‘one’. But, being ‘one’ is not the same as ‘equal’. Why didn’t the 3 servants in the parable of the talents receive an equal amount? Do all ‘humans’ have equal abilities?

**GEN 1:27** *So God created man in His own image; in the image of God He created him; male and female He created them.*

Every ‘creature’ God created had a role, a function. Man’s role was to reflect Gods glory, throughout all the earth.

**GEN 1:28** *Then God blessed them, and God said to them, “Be fruitful and multiply; fill the earth and subdue it;*

And, the woman was created for a specific purpose..

**GEN 2:18** *And the Lord God said, “It is not good that man should be alone; I will make him a helper comparable to him.”*

When you take a humanistic (man centred) view of scripture, you ‘judge’ terms, and all of God creations from man’s perspective. And, asking about equality of male and female is inviting this. And, no doubt any resulting ‘apologetic’ response could drag in scripture to support.

Asking, or trying to ‘work out’ whether God sees male and female as ‘equal’ is in some respects ridiculous. Now, if you meant...  ..”Do Christians see man and women as equal”? - I’m sure you’ll get some right sounding answers.